# OnCreateView not called in android fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist, android-nested-fragment

I have a listView on the left, and a nested fragment with checkBoxes on the right.

[image]

The checkBoxes are in an Arraylist declared globally. The ArrayList is created dynamically in the onCreateView method of the nestedFragment.

In the **onPause** method i save the checkboxes state.

The onclick listener of the listView, replaces the Fragments is this way:

```
 CheckNodesFragment checkNodesFragment = new CheckNodesFragment();

 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.child_fragmentB, checkNodesFragment);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**Problem:** When i click the Icarus or whatever listview item double times, the app crashes in the **onPause()**, since the
onCreateView method making all initializations  is not be called, but only onPause is called.

However, when i add and not replace the fragment all the lifecycles methods are called, and onCreateView() too, but when i add the fragment the screen's text becomes more bold with each add:
[image]

Comment: It crashes just when you click listitem twice really fast, or always after second click, regardless of delay between listitem clicks?

Comment: It crashes regardless of delay between listitem clicks. It crashes when i click twice the same list item (For instance the Icarus). When i click different listView items succesively, the app does not crash.

Comment: Is layout with id `child_fragmentB` FrameLayout or not?

Comment: Yes, it is FrameLayout!

Comment: When i replace the FRagment, firstly the onPause method is called and then onStop, onDestroyView, onResume e.t.c. 
Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, and i found that when i replace fragment, the first lifecycle fragment's call is the onPause method , and then onStop, onDestroyView e.t.c. Taking this into account i solved my problem.